Is there a way I can optimize this google sheets formula that I have to paste into many cells using ArrayFormula or the Query function?
I have a formula in google sheets that requires me to paste it into many cells. It is pretty long and complex, and I'm wondering if there is any way to make it shorter/more efficient for google sheets by either eliminating the pasting across all of the cells using an arrayformula or by using google API query language. Here is the formula:
=$D2+SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAYFORMULA(exp(-0.000792*((($A2- FILTER($A:$A,$B:$B=$C2,$C:$C<>$B2,$A:$A<$A2))))))/sum(ARRAYFORMULA(exp(-0.000792*((($A2- FILTER($A:$A,$B:$B=$C2,$C:$C<>$B2,$A:$A<$A2)))))))*FILTER(D:D,$B:$B=$C2,$C:$C<>$B2,$A:$A<$A2))))
Basically, I'm taking a number from Col D (which becomes $D3, $D4, etc.) and adding it to the sum of an arrayformula that calculates a weighted average using distance from date as weights that filters for the numbers to sum using conditions ($A:$A,$B:$B=$C2,$C:$C<>$B2,$A:$A<$A2).
Here is a layout of the table, where Date is Column A. I am filtering where the label in "Person 2" is listed as "Person 1" ($C2=$B:$B), excluding where "Person 1" is "Person 2" ($B2<>$C:$C) and future  results ($A:$A<$A2).
Date    Person 1    Person 2    Points
While the function works, I need to paste it into many cells, which takes a lot of time for Google Sheets to compute. If there is any optimization possible, I would greatly appreciate it!!!
Sorry if any of this is confusing, I'll be glad to answer any questions if needed!

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Thanks for the question. I've read and re-read it but, though it is explained in some detail, it is not enough to just cite the formula. The question also sample data and and worked examples. Would you please edit your question accordingly.
